# Where can I find the VclStylesinno.dll in order to be able to use VCL styles in my Inno Setup script?

Tags: inno-setup, vcl-styles

I've downloaded the `VCL styles` from

> https://github.com/RRUZ/vcl-styles-plugins

but I can't find the `VclStylesinno.dll` in there.
Here's what I have inside the `InnoSetup plugin` folder:

[image]

Where can I find the aforementioned `dll`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `VclStylesinno.dll` is part of the ["Installer VCL Styles for Inno Setup" package](https://github.com/RRUZ/vcl-styles-plugins/releases) (`SetupVCLStylesInno.exe`).

You need to install the package and then locate the `VclStylesinno.dll` in its installation folder. Just copy the dll over to your Inno Setup project. I believe it does not have any dependencies, so you do not need any other files from the installation (except for the .vsf style of your choice).